# How to say something is not a joke, meaning it is true, but it's a joke, meaning it's ironic, using the word joke?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

> Egypt, UK study finds, is second happiest nation.

Suppose you want to tell your reader this statement is true, but it's ironic that a country like Egypt ranks 2nd (given the immense suffering of its people on all levels), would the following capture this:

> This is not a joke, but almost one.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can go about doing this.  You could say, "I know it sounds like a joke, but it's true."

Answer (score 0):

One way I would go about this is by saying "Believe it or not, a UK study finds that Egypt is the second happiest nation".

The phrase "Believe it or not" gets across that the fact is a bit unusual and, if said in a certain tone, perhaps humorous.